# ASP.NET Core runtime (dynamic) configuration of external library settings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dynamic, configuration

in my service I have been following the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#options-interfaces) for setting up runtime configuration for my service using `IOptionsMonitor`. What I am doing now works fine for having runtime configuration updates:

```cs
class MySettings {
   //settings...
}

class Startup {
   //...
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
      services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration);
      services.AddSingleton<SomeSingleton>();
      //... more configuration
   }
}

class SomeSingleton {
  public SomeSingleton(IOptionsMonitor<MySettings> optionsMonitor) {
     //constructor...
  }
}
```

In the above example `SomeSingleton` is able to successfully see runtime updates from my configuration provider. Now however suppose there are two external (i.e. uneditable) classes I want to register:

```cs
class ExternalClassOne {
   public ExternalClassOne(ExternalClassOneSettings settings) {
     //constructor...
   }
}

class ExternalClassTwo {
   public ExternalClassOne(IOptions<ExternalClassTwoSettings> settings) {
     //constructor...
   }
}
```

Assuming `ExternalClassOneSettings` and `ExternalClassTwoSettings` are classes with just public `get/set` properties, is there anyway to enable runtime updates to `ExternalClassOneSettings` and `ExternalClassTwoSettings` for a singleton registration of either or both of `ExternalClassOne`/`ExternalClassTwo`?

Comment: Where the external classes located, A .net core Class Library or .Net standard Class Library?

Comment: @ZhiLv my question would be for either/or -- I've had this come up in both situations.